# Limit involving "e" and square

Tags: limits

I'm struggling with the following limit.

$$\lim_{n\to ∞} (e^n-2^n)^{1/n}$$

First off, $(e^n-2^n)^{1/n} \le (e^n)^{1/n}$.

Secondly, since $\lim_{n\to ∞} (1+1/n)^{n}=e$, then  $(e^n-2^n)^{1/n} \ge (1+1/n)^{n}$.

In addition, since $\lim_{n\to ∞} (e^n)^{1/n}=e$, then $\lim_{n\to ∞} (e^n-2^n)^{1/n}=e.$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: You second part doesn't make sense to me (the conclusion $\ge (1+\frac1n)^n$) but the limit is correct.

Comment: The limit is certainly $e$, but I do not understand the argument you give.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I was just trying to squeeze the original sequence inbetween the two sequences with more obvious limits.

Comment: The finding two sequences to squeeze between is a good idea. You found something "above." The "below" part was not carried out. You could have used the fact that $2^n\lt 0.8e^n$ for $n\ge 1$, making $e^n-2^n\gt $(0.2)e^n$. Now take the $n$-th root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can't say what is behind the first 'then'.

In this kind of problem, the systematic approach is to **factor out the dominant term** of each sums (here is is $e^n$ inside the parents, because $e > 2$).

Heuristically, you get
$$
(e^n + 2^n)^{1/n}\simeq (e^n )^{1/n} = e
$$
and more rigorously:
$$
(e^n + 2^n)^{1/n} = \left[ e^n \left(1 + \left(\frac 2e\right)\right)^n\right]^{1/n}
= e \left[  1 + \left(\frac 2e\right)^n\right]^{1/n}
$$now as
$$
0<\frac 2e < \frac 12
$$the term $$1 + \left(\frac 2e\right)^n$$ is bounded, and so
$$
\left[  1 + \left(\frac 2e\right)^n\right]^{1/n} \to 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\ \lim_{n\to\infty}(e^n-2^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[e^n\left(1-\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^n\right)\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}=$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}e\cdot\left[1-\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^n\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

now, since $\ e>2$, the second term tends to 1, so you get that the limit is $\ e$

Comment: I don't think it's at all obvious that the second term tends to 1.

Comment: (2/e)<1, so if you elevate it to n, for $\ n\to\infty$, it goes rapidly to zero, so you have only 1^(1/n) which tends to 1